# LuaSnip install errors through packer in neovim

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

Neovim version: v0.9.0
Terminal: WezTerm

I was trying to use plugins from the *L3MON4D3
/
LuaSnip*
GitHub repo for my snippets usage. Using packer as my plugin manager. Everything works fine except LuaSnip.

Here's the whole pakcer.lua file:

```
--  This file can be loaded by calling `lua require('plugins')` from your init.vim

-- Only required if you have packer configured as `opt`
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'

  use {
      'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.0',
      -- or                            , branch = '0.1.x',
      requires = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
  }

  use({
      'rose-pine/neovim',
      as = 'rose-pine',
      config = function()
          vim.cmd('colorscheme rose-pine')
      end
  })

  use('nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {run = ':TSUpdate'})
  use('nvim-treesitter/playground')
  use('theprimeagen/harpoon')
  use('mbbill/undotree')
  use('tpope/vim-fugitive')
  use('nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim')
  use {
      'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua',
      requires = {
          'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons', -- optional
      },
      config = function()
          require("nvim-tree").setup {}
      end
  }
  -- autocompletion
  use("hrsh7th/nvim-cmp") -- completion plugin
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-buffer") -- source for text in buffer
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-path") -- source for file system paths

  -- snippets
  use({
    "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
    -- follow latest release.
    tag = "v1.*", -- Replace <CurrentMajor> by the latest released major (first number of latest release)   
  })
  use("saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip") -- for autocompletion
  use("rafamadriz/friendly-snippets") -- useful snippets

end)
```

Errors here:

```
               packer.nvim - finished in 3.666s
 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
 ✗ Failed to update L3MON4D3/LuaSnip

 Press 'q' to quit
 Press '<CR>' to show more info
 Press 'd' to show the diff
 Press 'r' to revert an update
 Press 'R' to retry failed operations
```

I did what the repo asks me to do. But I just kept getting this error. What should I do to avoid this error?